# Geometry Operands - BBOX vs Within - What's the difference?

Tags: spatial-database, wms, wfs, ogc

What is the difference between the "BBOX" and "Within" spatial operators.

Can anyone please shed some light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Simple but effective diagram.

Points inside the Random Object would be a better result than points within the entire Bounding Box.

Comment: (+1 for diagram) Ahhh Excellent, thanks for the diagram.

Comment: The bounding box would not normally extend above or below the object.

Comment: True, but i get the point. Thanks

Comment: It's a stand alone bounding box not related to the random object. whuber is correct if directly related to the bounding box of the random object - purely an example to show the difference.